# Divide (and name) one group of columns by another group in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

After a (very scaring) dplyr pipeline I've ended up with a dataset like this:

```
year   A    B     C  [....] Z  count.A    count.B     count.C [....] count.Z
1999  10    20    10  ...   6      3          5           67    ...      6
2000   3    5      5  ...   7      5          2            5    ...      5
```

Some example data to reproduce:

```
df <- data.frame(year = c(1999, 2000), 
                 A = c(10, 20), 
                 B = c(3, 6), 
                 C = c(1, 2), 
                 count.A = c(1, 2), 
                 count.B = c(8, 9), 
                 count.C = c(5, 7))
```

What I really need is to combine each column with its "count" counterpart i.e.

```
weight.A = A / count.A, 
weight.B = B / count.B
```

I've to do that programmatically as I have hundreds of columns. Is there a way to do that in a dplyr pipeline?

Comment: What does this have to do with `rowSums`? You should probably edit the title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't store variables in column names. If you reshape your data to make it tidy, the calculation is really simple:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% gather(var, val, -year) %>%    # reshape to long
    separate(var, c('var', 'letter'), fill = 'left') %>%    # extract var from former col names
    mutate(var = coalesce(var, 'value')) %>%    # add name for unnamed var
    spread(var, val) %>%    # reshape back to wide
    mutate(weight = value / count)    # now this is very simple

#>   year letter count value     weight
#> 1 1999      A     1    10 10.0000000
#> 2 1999      B     8     3  0.3750000
#> 3 1999      C     5     1  0.2000000
#> 4 2000      A     2    20 10.0000000
#> 5 2000      B     9     6  0.6666667
#> 6 2000      C     7     2  0.2857143
```

Answer (score 4):

If your columns are consistently named (and easy enough to retrieve) you could easily do this using an `lapply`:

```
cols <- c("A","B","C")
df[,paste0("weighted.",cols)] <- lapply(cols, function(x) df[,x] / df[, paste0("count.",x)])

#  year  A B C count.A count.B count.C weighted.A weighted.B weighted.C
#1 1999 10 3 1       1       8       5         10  0.3750000  0.2000000
#2 2000 20 6 2       2       9       7         10  0.6666667  0.2857143
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the columns are in order, we can use `data.table`.  Specify the columns of interest in `.SDcols` and divide by subset of columns of Subset of Data.table with the other half and assign (`:=`) it to new columns

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, paste0("weighted.",names(df)[1:3]) := .SD[,1:3]/.SD[,4:6], .SDcols = A:count.C]
df
#   year  A B C count.A count.B count.C weighted.year weighted.A weighted.B
#1: 1999 10 3 1       1       8       5            10  0.3750000  0.2000000
#2: 2000 20 6 2       2       9       7            10  0.6666667  0.2857143
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can programmatically create a vector of all column names, here is how I'd do for your example above

```
for (c.name in c("A", "B", "C")) {
    c.weight <- sprintf("weight.%s", c.name)
    c.count <- sprintf("count.%s", c.name)
    df[,c.weight] <- df[,c.name] / df[,c.count]
}
```