# How to divide each of a range a variables by a second range of variables in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a range of columns containing the numerators of certain diseases, and a range of columns containing the denominators of the same diseases. I want to loop through each of the numerator columns dividing by the appropriate denominator column creating a percentage column for each disease.

All my columns follow the same name format, disease1_num, disease2_num, disease1_den, disease1_den

I want to divide disease1_num/disease1_den*100 to create disease1_perc, then disease2_num/disease2_den*100 to create disease2_perc etc.

There are approximately 20 diseases in my dataset.

I am mainly using tidyverse commands.

I have tried using gather to create two datasets, one with the numerators, one with the denominator, extracted the diseasename, joined them together, calculated the percentage and then spread the dataset again, before adding this back to the original dataset, which does work but it is a bit long winded, ideally I would like to do this in place in the original dataset.

```r
# A tibble: 3 x 5
     id disease1_num disease2_num disease1_den disease2_den
  <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
1     1            5            4           12           15
2     2            8            6           14           16
3     3           10            8           17           18


df_num <- df %>%
  select(id,disease1_num:disease2_num) %>% 
  gather(key="num_indicator",value="num",disease1_num:disease2_num) %>% 
  mutate(indicator=str_remove(num_indicator,'_num'))

df_den <- df%>%
  select(id, disease1_den:disease2_den) %>% 
  gather(key="den_indicator",value="den",disease1_den:disease2_den) %>% 
  mutate(indicator=str_remove(den_indicator,'_den'))

df_numden <- left_join(df_num,df_den,c('id','indicator'))                             

df_perc <- df_numden %>% 
  mutate(perc_indicator=str_replace(den_indicator,'den','perc'),
         perc=num/den*100) %>% 
  select(id, perc_indicator:perc) %>%
  spread(perc_indicator,perc)

df_final <- left_join(df,df_perc,'id')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43990091/divide-and-name-one-group-of-columns-by-another-group-in-dplyr

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Divide (and name) one group of columns by another group in dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43990091/divide-and-name-one-group-of-columns-by-another-group-in-dplyr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can just use `grep` to get column indices and divide directly.

```
num_cols <- grep("num$", names(df), value = TRUE)
den_cols <- grep("den$", names(df), value = TRUE)
df[sub("_num","_perc", num_cols)]<- df[num_cols]/df[den_cols] * 100

df
#  id disease1_num disease2_num disease1_den disease2_den disease1_perc disease2_perc
#1  1            5            4           12           15          41.7          26.7
#2  2            8            6           14           16          57.1          37.5
#3  3           10            8           17           18          58.8          44.4
```

Note that you need to be sure that you have same number of `num_cols` and `den_cols`.

Comment: Thanks Ronak, I realised i have simplified my question a bit much, the disease1 is the name of a disease which changes each time, e.g. af007 then disease2 is bp002, is there a way to extract the name of column as well? They always end in _num and _den